# Does Model::create make a db transaction

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I came up to such code for one-to-one insert:

```
$anotherPet = \App\Pet::create($data);
$anotherUser = \App\User::create($data);
$anotherPet->user()->associate($anotherUser);

$anotherPet->save();
```

Does `create()` make a call to db or the transaction is made on `save()` ?

3 vs 1 calls?

Appreciate your kind help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using laravel, create does a transaction, if you want only one you can do create a new instance and fill it like this :

```
$anotherPet = new \App\Pet;
$anotherPet->fill($data);
$anotherUser = \App\User::create($data); // transaction is made here; mandatory to have an id for your association

$anotherPet->user()->associate($anotherUser); // no transaction
$anotherPet->save(); // transaction is made here
```

this way you have 2 queries instead of 3, i don't a way to make it in a single query without a foreign key constraint fail.

Comment: They are 2 instances and foreign keys constraints are involved so that's why I came up to that pattern :(
Can I `associate()` with `fill()` ?

Comment: in this case you will have to save the object you want to associate before associating it, otherwise you won't have the primary key.
i updated the first answer